# Return JSON response without redirecting

Tags: json, ajax, django

I'm new with django and i'm trying to update fields in my view without redirecting, i'm trying to return a JSON file when a view function is called, but i can't seem to find how to do so withouth redirecting to some url.

I think it may have something to do with my urls.py: ... path('#', views.myFunction, name='myFunctionName').

I'm messing arround with the django tutorial that appears in djangoproject.com

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
<li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize }}</li
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
<a href="{% url 'polls:myfunction' %}">doFunction</a>
```

my view function goes like this:

```
def myfunction(request):
    return JsonResponse({'ayy':'lmao'})
```

and the urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path


from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
path(r'#', views.myfunction, name='myfunction'),
path('form', views.FormView.as_view(), name='form'),
```

Comment: What kind of view do you use ? Can you add some code from urls.py, views.py and the html template ? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Andy i just updated my question with the info you asked me, thanks in advance

Comment: You can not use path with a regular expression in Django 2+ you need to import re_path and then you can use a re_path(r'#/', views.myfunction, name="myfunction")

Comment: @ThomasMyers hi, the route that i wrote may be wrong, so don't mind it, the only thing i need is to send a Json file to the client and with some js change some html content, but every time i use JsonResponse it redirects due to my urls.py configuration

Comment: what url is it redirecting too?

Comment: @Thomas Myers it creates a url like this /%23

Answer (score 0):

So what is most likely happening here is the Django URLS is finding the index page and redirecting to that view. The # pound or number symbol usually indicates a redirect in page.

Answer (score 0):

First, there's no AJAX in your code. `<a href="{% url 'polls:myfunction' %}">doFunction</a>` will redirect to an entire new page.
Second, your path to `myfunction` in urls.py is not correct.

Here's an example of what you can do. I also suggest you to read [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html). I use JQuery but feel free to adapt with what you prefer.

urls.py:

```
    #...
    path('ajax/domyfunction/', views.myfunction, name='myfunction')
]
```

html template:

```
<h1>{{ question.question_text }}</h1>
<ul>
{% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
<li>{{ choice.choice_text }} -- {{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes|pluralize}}</li
{% endfor %}
</ul>
<a href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
<button id="b_function">doFunction</button>
<script>
$("#b_function").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '{% url "polls:myfunction" %}',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.ayy);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```